# Bootstrap Accordion Panel/Collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, panel

My Bootstrap accordian is acting temperamental! I have created three panels displayed in a column grid, but the 2nd, and 3rd collapse menu closes the wrong menu (e.g. clicking/opening menu2 then clicking/opening menu3 will close menu2 before opening menu3).

Any idea why?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a class="panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          My Story
          </h4>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a class="panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          My Skills
          </h4>
        </div>
        </a>                            
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
          Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a class="panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          My Ambition
          </h4>
        </div>
        </a>                            
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to number the accordion i.e. accordion1 accordion2 accordion3

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <a class="panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                    My Story
                    </h4>
                </div>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <a class="panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                    My Skills
                    </h4>
                </div>
                </a>                            
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <a class="panel-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseThree">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                    My Ambition
                    </h4>
                </div>
                </a>                            
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh-Oh Speghetti-Ohs :) Thanks Zeeba, would vote you up but i'm still a noob (as you may see already :)